# nested section scroll 100vh

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to do a section that is fixed when you scroll it start to scroll the inner articles by 100vh
inside the section like having a a block of section 100vh , and scroll the inner articles by 100vh :

HTML :

```
  <section class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis similique 
  expedita dolore, suscipit, 
  velit temporibus iusto ad, praesentium officia nemo nihil rerum necessitatibus excepturi 
  possimus 
   tempora maxime quam dolor culpa.</section>

<section id="process">
      <article><h1>THIS IS ARTICLE 1</h1></article>
      <article><h1>THIS IS ARTICLE 2</h1></article>
      <article><h1>THIS IS ARTICLE 3</h1></article>
      <article><h1>THIS IS ARTICLE 4</h1></article>
      <article><h1>THIS IS ARTICLE 5</h1></article>

</section>
    
<section class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facilis 
similique expedita dolore, suscipit, 
velit temporibus iusto ad, praesentium officia nemo nihil rerum necessitatibus excepturi 
possimus 
tempora maxime quam dolor culpa.</section>
```

CSS :

```
#process{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5rem;
    height: 100vh;

}
#process article{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.lorem{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

all i want to do when you scroll into the 2nd section it goes fixed in the screen and when you scroll only the inner articles change inside the section with the same background after finish reading the articles it goes to the 3rd section , how can i achieve that ?

EDIT :

[something like this](http://codepen.io/natjo/pen/aboLBzQ)

Comment: Do you mean this https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html ?

Comment: yes , but only scroll inside the 2nd section until articles finish then goes to 3rd section

Comment: any solution guys , i cannot solve this . ;s

Comment: Look For the library parallax.js it’s fairly complex but I think you achieve what you want, you need to look for examples and the reference. Try it out

Comment: parallax.js doesn't make what i need , i just need a scrolling section like this example above

Comment: up up up up. ;(

Answer (score 0):

decrease the height for better view and what is your question about ..

Comment: what i want to do is making a page that when you go to the 2nd section is start to be scroll-behavier : smooth , then when you start scrolling into the page it only scroll articles inside of the section not the body page after articles finished it goes to the 3rd section .

Comment: so u want a view which can automatically switch from first section to another @JhonDonald

Comment: yes what i want to acheive is something like this :

https://codepen.io/natjo/pen/aboLBzQ

but into the articles

Comment: please can someone help me with this , i cannot figure out how to do this , any help ?